# QML Stylizing Button with singleton theme.qml

Tags: qt, button, qml, styles, themes

I have a singleton .qml file for theme definitions: (theme/DarkTheme.qml)

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.4

QtObject {
    property var btn: {
        "primary": {
            color: "#21be2b",
            downColor: "#7721be2b",
            textColor: "#21be2b",
            textDownColor: "#ffffff"
        },
    }

    property color disableColor: "#999999"
    property color transparent: "#00000000"

    // Primary Button
    property QtObject btn_bg: Rectangle {
        color: parent ? parent.down ? btn.primary.downColor : transparent : transparent
        opacity: enabled ? 1 : 0.7
        border.color: enabled ? parent ? btn.primary.color : btn.primary.color : disableColor
        border.width: 1
        radius: 7
    }
    property QtObject btn_fg: Text {
        text: parent ? parent.text : ""
        font.pixelSize: 24
        opacity: enabled ? 1.0 : 0.5
        color: enabled ? parent ? parent.down ? btn.primary.textDownColor : btn.primary.textColor : btn.primary.textColor : disableColor
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
    }
}
```

qmldir:

```
singleton Theme theme/DarkTheme.qml
```

Then I set the `btn_bg` and `btn_fg` to my buttons to stylize them:

```
Button {
    width: 140
    height: 60
    text: "Button"
    background: Theme.btn_bg
    contentItem: Theme.btn_fg
}
Button {
    x: 90
    y: 90
    width: 140
    height: 60
    text: "Button2"
    background: Theme.btn_bg
    contentItem: Theme.btn_fg
}
```

If I use one button only, it works perfectly, but when I use two buttons with same theme background and contentItems, it is not working.

---

How can I manage to achieve a easy system like this, `Button{}`s uses same background and foreground but clones the theme Rectangle not directly uses it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to do it with making a new component called `FButton.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import "../"

Button {
    property string theme: "primary"
    property var themeObj: Theme.buttons[theme]

    background: Rectangle {
        color: parent.down ? themeObj.downColor : Theme.transparent
        opacity: enabled ? 1 : 0.7
        border.color: enabled ? themeObj.color : Theme.disableColor
        border.width: 1
        radius: 7
    }
    contentItem: Text {
        text: parent.text
        font.pixelSize: 24
        opacity: enabled ? 1.0 : 0.5
        color: enabled ? parent.down ? themeObj.textDownColor : themeObj.textColor : Theme.disableColor
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
    }
}
```

and `theme/DarkTheme.qml` is now like this:

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.4

QtObject {
    property var buttons: {
        "primary": {
            color: "#21be2b",
            downColor: "#7721be2b",
            textColor: "#21be2b",
            textDownColor: "#ffffff"
        },
        "warn": {
            color: "#bebe2b",
            downColor: "#77bebe2b",
            textColor: "#FFbe2b",
            textDownColor: "#ffffff"
        },
        "danger": {
            color: "#be212b",
            downColor: "#77be212b",
            textColor: "#FF212b",
            textDownColor: "#ffffff"
        },
    }

    property color disableColor: "#999999"
    property color transparent: "#00000000"
}
```

---

So, now I can use it like this:

```
FButton {
    x: 20
    y: 20
    width: 140
    height: 60
    text: "Button"
    theme: "primary"
}

FButton {
    x: 20
    y: 90
    width: 140
    height: 60
    text: "Button2"
    theme: "primary"
}
```